# Angular UI router, how to get a list of ancestors of current state from controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

My states hierarchy is (from top to bottom):

1. `root`
2. `account`
3. `account.invoices`
4. `account.invoices.detail`

When I'm in  `account.invoices.detail` state I'd like to get a list of ancestors states:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('InvoiceDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
        var current = $state.current.name;
        // Get ancestors from current state
        // Tried $state.current.parent, $state.parent, $state.parent(current)
    }]);
```

Angular UI router allows you to get transition to parent state (i.e. from a view with `data-ui-sref="^"`), so it should be possible to achieve this (follow up the chain of ancestors up to `root`).

I need this to build a auto-breadcrumbs-like functionality.

**EDIT**: ended up with this, thanks to the accepted answer:

```
var current = $scope.$state.$current,
     parent = current.parent,
     ancestors = [current.name];

while (typeof parent != 'undefined' && parent.name.length) {
    ancestors.push(parent.name);
    parent = parent.parent;
}
```

If you ask why the check for `parent.name.length` its because there is something like a "root" state in Angular UI (can't get any documentation about).

Comment: As you said, you can do it by interrogating the parents or the parents and building the list yourself. AFAIK there is no method that returns a list of ancestors for a particular state.

Comment: @Wawy how do i interrogate the parent of current state? From inside the controller i mean...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at `$state.$current.includes`; it appears to return an object with keys matching the current and parent states. I believe these are all states that would pass a `$state.includes()` test.

Comment: What I was looking for, thanks so much! I've used `.parent` instead of `.includes`.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
function getParentList(state) {
 var parentList = [];
 var state = state.parent;
 while(state) {
  parentList.push(state.toString());
  state = state.parent;
 }
 return parentList;
}

var parents = getParentList($state.$current);
```

Comment: Yes but `state.parent` is `undefined` when you use the notation `parent.child` (dot notation).